# Cannot call open file window function built with wxPython from another function

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to call the open file window using wxPython from another function:

```
import wx
class get_path:
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_path('*.txt')
    def getPath(wildcard):
        app = wx.App(None)
        style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dialog.GetPath()
        else:
            path = None
        dialog.Destroy()
        return path
```

The code does not work for some reason but it works if it is called directly in a file as below:

```
import wx
def get_path(wildcard):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_MULTIPLE | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(
        None, 
        'Open', 
        wildcard=wildcard, 
        style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = None
    dialog.Destroy()
    return path
print get_path('*.txt')
```

Does anyone see the error here?

Comment: If code doesn't work then show full error message. BTW: you try to use function `self.get_path()` but you define `def getPath()` - different names.

Answer (score 0):

You use `self.get_path()` but you define `def getPath()` different names. And you forgot `self` in `def get_path(self, wildcard)`. Constructor can't return value so you have to create object and then call method which can return value.

BTW: use CamelCase names for class names

```
import wx

class MyGetPath: # use CamelCase names for classes

    def get_path(self, wildcard):
        app = wx.App(None)
        style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST

        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dialog.GetPath()
        else:
            path = None

        dialog.Destroy()

        return path

result = MyGetPath().get_path('*.txt')

print(result)
```

Or you can create static method, and then you don't have to create object - `MyGetPath` is without `()`

```
import wx

class MyGetPath: # use CamelCase names for classes

    @staticmethod
    def get_path(wildcard):
        app = wx.App(None)
        style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST

        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dialog.GetPath()
        else:
            path = None

        dialog.Destroy()

        return path

result = MyGetPath.get_path('*.txt')

print(result)
```